# How do I fix my Minecraft sorting machine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am currently playing on a Minecraft server. I want to build a sorting machine, but the normal sorting machine is not working.

I want to filter all the items which are only stackable up to 16. The sorting system can works if the items stackable up to 16 are above 12 and the items stackable up to 64 are under 48.

Inside the hopper: | 0 | 17 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Items.

For item stackable to 64: reading the hopper with a comparator, it turns off the other comparator at 49.

For items stackable to 16: reading the hopper with a comparator, it turns off the other comparator at 13.

My Idea was to stack the items between 13 and 48. Every item that is stackable up to 64 passes through because it won't turn of the comparator. Every item that is stackable up to 16 is falling down, because it turns off the comparator. I don't have any idea how to stack the items in a hopper between 13 and 48.

[image]

How do I fix my sorting machine?

Comment: Some Questions: What minecraft version are you using? Bedrock or Java? Also, what update are you in?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a locking signal back into the hopper (so that everything doesn't drain)?

Comment: I am playing minecraft Java 1.12.2 

I have not tried it with a locking signal. But i do not think it is working. Because the Items are going to stack in the other hopper

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I'm having trouble understanding the question/problem that you are describing. I'm guessing that you simply want to sort 16 stack items from 64 stack items. Here is my solution.

The size of the stacks in the hoppers is important to maintain the correct comparator redstone levels. Since there are only three items in minecraft with stack size of 16 we can simply modify a standard item sorter to accommodate your needs. This is a proof tested solution to the problem. Do not adjust your volume, I didn't talk. I just recorded this real quick with no editing.

Edit: Afterward I realized that I forgot about empty buckets. Just add a forth column for empty buckets and set it up just like the others.